# How to apply agg to a dataframe with multiindex with different functions according level?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to apply a different function to a dataframe with multiindex according to the second level of the index.

For instance, for the dataframe:

```py
In [4]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,6,7],'b': [7,1,4,5]}, index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples( 
   ...:     [('x','tmax'),('x','tmin'),('y','tmax'), ('y','tmin')]))                                                          

In [5]: df                                                                                                                    
Out[5]: 
        a  b
x tmax  1  7
  tmin  2  1
y tmax  6  4
  tmin  7  5
```

I want to have the maximum value of the row when the index is (-, tmax) and the minimum value when the index is (-, tmin), for instance:

```py
        value
x tmax      7
  tmin      1
y tmax      6
  tmin      5
```

I have tried with agg but I don't know how to apply the max and min functions according to the value of the multiindex:

```py
df.agg({'tmax': np.max, 'tmin': np.min}, axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) and aggregate functions:

```
s = pd.concat([df.xs('tmax', level=1, drop_level=False).max(1),
               df.xs('tmin', level=1, drop_level=False).min(1)]).sort_index()
print (s)
x  tmax    7
   tmin    1
y  tmax    6
   tmin    5
dtype: int64
```

Or filter by second level if only values `tmax` and `tmin` use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
m = df.index.get_level_values(1) == 'tmax'

s = pd.Series(np.where(m, df.max(1), df.min(1)), index=df.index)
print (s)
x  tmax    7
   tmin    1
y  tmax    6
   tmin    5
dtype: int64
```